# Markdown algorithm: string difficulties

Tags: java, string, markdown

I started writing this algorithm:

```
public static String convert(String str) {
    if (str.equals("# "))
        return " ";

    if (str.matches("#+.+")) {
        int n = str.length() - str.replaceFirst("#+", "").length();
        return "<h" + n + ">" + str.substring(n) + "<h" + n + ">";
    }

    return str;
}
}
```

So when I type, ####title, it returns < h4>title< /h4>

My problem is that when I write ####title###title, I would like it to return < h4>title< /h4> < h3>title< /h3> but it only returns < h4>title< /h4>...What am I doing wrong???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because you are using the pattern: - `#+.+`.

Now, since `.` matches everything in Regex, so in the above pattern, it matches `everything` after an `initial set` of `#'s`.

So, for your input: - **####title###title**, your pattern will match: -

- `#+` will match `####`
- `.+` will match `title###title`

You need to change your regex to : - `(#+[^#]+)`, and probably need to use [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class here to get the desired output, becaues you want to match `every` part of your string to the given `pattern`.

`#+[^#]+` -> Will match the first set of `#` and then everything after that, except `#`. So it stops where the next set of `#'s` start.

Here's how you can use it: -

```
    String str = "####title###title";  // str is the method parameter
    if (str.equals("# "))
        System.out.println(" ");

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(#+[^#]+)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        String str1 = matcher.group(1);
        int n = str1.length() - str1.replaceFirst("#+", "").length();
        System.out.println("<h" + n + ">" + str1.substring(n) + "</h" + n + ">");
    }
```

**OUTPUT**: -

```
<h4>title</h4>
<h3>title</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing only the first occurrence of #+. Try replacing the if with a while and instead of return inside the if, append the result into a StringBuilder.

Something like:

```
String str = "####title###title2"; 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (str.matches("#+.+")) {          
        int n = str.length() - str.replaceFirst("#+", "").length();
         str = str.replaceFirst("#+", "");
        int y = str.length();
        if(str.matches(".+#+.+")) {
            y = str.indexOf("#");
            sb.append( "<h" + n + ">" + str.substring(0,y) + "<h" + n + ">");
            str = str.substring(y, str.length());
        } else {
            sb.append( "<h" + n + ">" + str.substring(0,y) + "<h" + n + ">");
        }

    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());

}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't give the desired output. And there is a compiler error. You used `length` instead of `length()` with string.

Comment: yhea, well, I've mentioned "Something like" in my answer

Answer (score 0):

You are matching wrong string, try this one:

```
#+[^#]+
```

And of course you want to make call it recursivly or in a loop